# Can you get onscreen notifications working on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, notifications

I use windows notifications with my Gulp setup. When I compile my code (on **windows 8.1**) — I would get a notification handled by Windows in the top right of my screen.

On windows 10 however, they've moved the notifications into the 'action centre', which means I can no longer see my notification coming up telling me if my code has failed or passed — without manually going into that area constantly which is annoying. So can you enable them to appear onscreen at all?

Comment: Try disabling either [Notification Center](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-notification-center-in-windows-10/) or the [Notification](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-notifications-in-windows-10/) itself. FWIW, uTorrent and Firefox still show onscreen notifications on my Windows 10 install, so its either our install have different config or Gulp require update for handling Windows 10 notification API

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. In Settings -> System -> Notifications and actions.
Find **toast**, click on it and enable all toggles

Comment: Looks as though that was already enabled here for me. It must be a plugin based issue perhaps. I will keep looking. But thank you!